# How do I increase the height of a menu divider in a navigation?

Tags: html, css, header

Here's what I got.  I need to increase the height of the divider (|) in between the menu options.  How do I do it so that it takes up the entire header area only?

HTML:

```
 <header>
 <img src="/images/logo.png" height="50px" id="front" />
 <nav>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 <div id="second_line"></div>
 </header>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
 margin: 0;
 }
 header {
 background-color: #009000;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
 }
 #front {
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 }
 nav {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 30px;
 }
 ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 }
 ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
 border-right: 2px solid black;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 }
 ul li.last {
 border-right: 0px;
 }
 #second_line {
 margin-top:10px;
 height:3px;
 background-color: #FECE2C;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: "logo is on the left not the right"  just put <div style="clear:both"></div> before <div id="second_line"></div>

Comment: @rusly I am sorry I asked the wrong question at the end.  I only need the length of the | to increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    **line-height:30px;**
}
```